# Installing Java on Chroot Solaris

Tags: solaris, java

I have recently created a chrooted environment on a Solaris 10 box. If have installed jdk 7 to this 'jail'. It is not running. When I try `./java -version`, I get the following error:

```
guarantee(mem_serialize_page != NULL) failed: mmap Failed for memory serialize page
```

The log file doesn't help either. Have any of you seen this error before? I have tried Googling it but there is very little information on it.

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
Internal Error (os_solaris.cpp:4995), pid=817, tid=2
guarantee(mem_serialize_page != NULL) failed: mmap Failed for memory serialize page

JRE version: 7.0-b147
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing solaris-x86 )
Core dump written. Default location: /jdk1.7.0/bin/core or core.817
```

Comment: Any chance of looking at the core-dump? Might be interesting to see the args to mmap().

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Can you tell me how to read a core dump? Is it a dump on the whole box or just the jail? pstack?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included links to /dev and /devices in your chroot environment?  How about /proc?

Comment: Yes, I have included those. I have mounted proc and dev/nul, dev/zero and dev/log. Is there any I'm missing? This is becoming a real drag. I'm on the verge of abandoning this method.

Comment: I suggest you try using truss to find why the mmap call is failing - for example mmap is often used to open /dev/zero to allocate space.  If that fails for any reason it could cause the errors you are seeing.